# How to type interdependent Props in typescript 3.8?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a Table component with a set of props like following:

```
type Props = {
  data: Aray<Object>,
  columns: Array<Column>,
  apiSearch?: boolean,
  fetchData?: (params) => void,
}

const Table = (props: Props) => {
 const onFilterChange = (filter) => {
   if (apiSearch) {
     fetchData(filter); // Getting possibly undefined error here. Is there a way to make typescript understand this function will be present if apiSearch is true??
   }
 };

 return (
   <TableComponent {...props} onFilter={onFilterChange} />
 )
};
```

I'm trying to type `fetchdata` in such a way that it should be a function if `apiSearch` is true and optional in other case.

I tried defining two Types like:

```
type WithApiSearch = {
  apiSearch: true;
  fetchSearchData: (params: object) => void;
};

type WithoutApiSearch = {
  apiSearch: undefined | false;
};

type Props = CommonProps & (WithApiSearch | WithoutApiSearch);
```

This is not showing any error if `fetchData` is not provided and `apiSearch` is true. I don't know if this possible and I am new to typescript.

Answer (score 0):

With only conditional keys :

Look at the following [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=29&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbwFBSgQzAEsBlCfOAYwAsAuKYOAVwgBpcoAzCYGgEXzB89ABRgK+ALbJ6+AHYgAlOgB8UAG4IiAE3YBfKAB8sHPIVLkqdLvgA2yNqa49+g-AH56nOw-3ZslAhyyMBQACr4AEa20BhiiCj08EjIymhqmHr+EdEQIjhmxGQUNPSMLOx43LzUAkJePo56igDc2VEx+RzmxVZlzI5VLrVuomkZevqt7bldhRYl1t72g841dcJQIuNYk9jNbdg5nQUERZalNiuVa671V777rUA)

```
type Props = {
  apiSearch: true,
  fetchData: (params: any) => void,
} | {
    apiSearch: false,
    fetchData?: false,
}

const Table = (props: Props) => {}

// Error
Table({
  apiSearch: true,
  fetchData: false,
});

// Ok
Table({
  apiSearch: true,
  fetchData: () => {},
});

// Error
Table({
  apiSearch: false,
  fetchData: () => {},
});

// Ok
Table({
  apiSearch: false,
  fetchData: false,
});
```

---

Now mixing conditional keys and regular keys :

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=36&pc=4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwCYEtgsQQwDYAUBOcYAzlALxQDeAUFFJmCgMoSb4DGAFgFxTD4BXCABpaUAGYRgXACKZgmXgAowbTAFtivTAhABKcgD4oANzgokogL5QAPlTENmrDjwk5iIsZOmc5CgH5ecQ8vK2pqFARgCHwQ9mgCImIAIUxPBzpxODggqGJ+KIBzUToAIzY8spzsVgRrCNBIKCSSchbCEjSMgDJYRFR0LDxO4gBuCPZEAqgAFUwy2vaVUd5W4gMyY0pw6nnFiCUaOicWNi5efiFSiSlZeUV3bE9rPQm9hdqjx0Yz10vBF4snc-A9lJttlZXu99l9jvRfi4Lk8Xt4Qf5HkoIVQodQrG8IrDDvDTki3CFnkDbr4McFQtCgA)

```
type ConditionalProps = {
  apiSearch: true,
  fetchData: (params: any) => void,
} | {
  apiSearch: false,
  fetchData?: false,
}

interface PropsBase {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: boolean,
}

type Props = PropsBase & ConditionalProps;

const Table = (props: Props) => {}

Table({
  apiSearch: true,
  fetchData: false,
});

Table({
  apiSearch: true,
  fetchData: () => {},
});

Table({
  apiSearch: false,
  fetchData: () => {},
});

Table({
  apiSearch: false,
  fetchData: false,
});
```

Comment: it's not working anymore with latest typescript :(